# Wordpress required install plugin when activate plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want when i active plugin A, if plugin B not installed, i will required install plugin B.

Look like required plugin when install theme.

How i can do that? Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You will put this code in Plugin A :

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'A_on_activation' );

function A_on_activation(){
    if ( ! is_plugin_active( 'plugin-directory/B-plugin-file.php' ) ) {
        //Do what you want 
    } 
}
```

Comment: what's the best to do inside that? Automatically install missing WordPress plugin is not possible? post a request for installation?